# Mapping DataTypes from C to Java

Tags: java, c

There are some data types which are present in C but not available in Java. I have listed some of them and written their substitute in Java. Please suggest if i have done it correctly or some changes should be made:

unsigned char -> short

unsigned short -> int

unsigned char *x -> short[] x

unsigned short *x -> int[] x

char *x -> String

unsigned int -> long

Comment: @OliCharlesworth i am working on a project and i need to write equivalent(sort of convert) of C code in java.

Comment: Ok.  But you need to bear in mind that data types in C don't have standardised sizes, unlike those in Java.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Thats the biggest problem. Thats why i posted this question. I have assumed that C code is for 32 bit machine

Comment: char in java are unsigned !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `unsigned char` you should use Java's `char`, which is also unsigned. The others are OK inasmuch as they are injective (assuming commonly used sizes in C), i.e. they will preserve values, though the matter is rather more complicated with pointers/arrays.

Comment: I used short because char in Java represents unicode character which may lead to some problems.

Comment: @Rog Matthews: arbitrarily encoded text data is generally represented as a byte[] in Java - you won't find a method to e.g. convert a short[] to String. Given that the C standard guarantees that char and byte have the same size, it would be better to map an unsigned char in C to a signed byte in Java.

Comment: @Rog Matthews: it will of course blow up if a byte is anything but 8 bits - architectures like that exist, but you're unlikely to encounter them.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following

unsigned char -> char (16-bit) or short (15-bit) or /* signed*/ byte (8-bit)

unsigned short -> int or  /* signed */ short.

unsigned char *x -> byte[] x

unsigned short *x -> short[] x

char *x -> String or char[] or a Custom class which wraps a byte[]

unsigned int -> long or /* signed */ int

In many case you can use the signed type when previously you would have used the unsigned type.  Often you need minor workarounds, but sometimes you don't need to do anything.

Comment: That is true, but if you have data which is 8-bit characters, you can either use char, short or byte.

Answer (score 0):

java has following primitive data types,
byte
short
int 
long
float
double
char
boolean false

for unsigned char* x you should use String or char[] or byte[]
for unsigned char you should use char
and for unsigned int you can use int or long (depends)